# Closest Pattern Matching

Tags: regex

I am trying to identify citations within text. I can use LEX to define and match the citation patterns. However, this only works when the citations are correct. There tend to be A LOT of subtle errors in the documents.

These variations generally are not speling erors. The most common errors are missing punctuation or citation elements.

Question: is there some effective table driven method to do close matches? A possible variation on LEX? Or maybe a LEX programming technique (like error in YACC).

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting this question because I see no one answered you.

**With usual regex engine: no**

As you've probably found out, with most engines, regex is not the best tool for doing close matches or arbitrary words or phrases. Sure, at the most basic level, something like `\bs?he\b` will find either `he` or `she`... But to find all close matches in a word such as `interactive`, you'd have to generate a regex that introduces a number of permutations in the word... Neither efficient nor effective.

**One exception**

The one exception I know of is Matthew Burnett's `[regex][1]` module for Python. To start with, it's a terrific engine, one of the only two that I know (with .NET) that supports infinite-width lookbehinds. (JGSoft supports it too, but it's not tied to a language.)

This engine has a `fuzzymatch` mode that might just do what you want. You can provide a "cost equation" (max number of substitutions and so on).

You'd have to hook up Python to your data... There might be a module available for that.

Here's an excerpt from the doc.

> Regex usually attempts an exact match, but sometimes an approximate,
>   or "fuzzy", match is needed, for those cases where the text being
>   searched may contain errors in the form of inserted, deleted or
>   substituted characters.
>
> A fuzzy regex specifies which types of errors are permitted, and,
>   optionally, either the minimum and maximum or only the maximum
>   permitted number of each type. (You cannot specify only a minimum.)
>
> The 3 types of error are:
>
> Insertion, indicated by "i" Deletion, indicated by "d" Substitution,
>   indicated by "s"
>
> In addition, "e" indicates any type of error.
>
> The fuzziness of a regex item is specified between "{" and "}" after
>   the item.
>
> Examples:
>
> foo match "foo" exactly
>
> (?:foo){i} match "foo", permitting insertions
>
> (?:foo){d} match "foo", permitting deletions
>
> (?:foo){s} match "foo", permitting substitutions
>
> (?:foo){i,s} match "foo", permitting insertions and substitutions
>
> (?:foo){e} match "foo", permitting errors
>
> If a certain type of error is specified, then any type not specified
>   will not be permitted.
>
> In the following examples I'll omit the item and write only the
>   fuzziness.
>
> {i<=3} permit at most 3 insertions, but no other types
>
> {d<=3} permit at most 3 deletions, but no other types
>
> {s<=3} permit at most 3 substitutions, but no other types
>
> {i<=1,s<=2} permit at most 1 insertion and at most 2 substitutions,
>   but no deletions
>
> {e<=3} permit at most 3 errors
>
> {1<=e<=3} permit at least 1 and at most 3 errors
>
> {i<=2,d<=2,e<=3} permit at most 2 insertions, at most 2 deletions, at
>   most 3 errors in total, but no substitutions
>
> It's also possible to state the costs of each type of error and the
>   maximum permitted total cost.
>
> Examples:
>
> {2i+2d+1s<=4} each insertion costs 2, each deletion costs 2, each
>   substitution costs 1, the total cost must not exceed 4
>
> {i<=1,d<=1,s<=1,2i+2d+1s<=4} at most 1 insertion, at most 1 deletion,
>   at most 1 substitution; each insertion costs 2, each deletion costs 2,
>   each substitution costs 1, the total cost must not exceed 4
>
> You can also use "<" instead of "<=" if you want an exclusive minimum
>   or maximum:
>
> {e<=3} permit up to 3 errors
>
> {e<4} permit fewer than 4 errors
>
> {0
>
> By default, fuzzy matching searches for the first match that meets the
>   given constraints. The ENHANCEMATCH flag will cause it to attempt to
>   improve the fit (i.e. reduce the number of errors) of the match that
>   it has found.
>
> The BESTMATCH flag will make it search for the best match instead.
>
> Further examples to note:
>
> regex.search("(dog){e}", "cat and dog")[1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) returns "cat" because that
>   matches "dog" with 3 errors, which is within the limit (an unlimited
>   number of errors is permitted).
>
> regex.search("(dog){e<=1}", "cat and dog")[1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) returns " dog" (with a
>   leading space) because that matches "dog" with 1 error, which is
>   within the limit (1 error is permitted).
>
> regex.search("(?e)(dog){e<=1}", "cat and dog")[1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) returns "dog"
>   (without a leading space) because the fuzzy search matches " dog" with
>   1 error, which is within the limit (1 error is permitted), and the
>   (?e) then makes it attempt a better fit.
>
> In the first two examples there are perfect matches later in the
>   string, but in neither case is it the first possible match.
>
> The match object has an attribute fuzzy_counts which gives the total
>   number of substitutions, insertions and deletions.
>
> A 'raw' fuzzy match:
>   regex.fullmatch(r"(?:cats|cat){e<=1}", "cat").fuzzy_counts (0, 0, 1)
>   0 substitutions, 0 insertions, 1 deletion.
>
> A better match might be possible if the ENHANCEMATCH flag used:
>   regex.fullmatch(r"(?e)(?:cats|cat){e<=1}", "cat").fuzzy_counts (0, 0, 0)
>   0 substitutions, 0 insertions, 0 deletions.